# Все время вылазит ошибка - ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я пишу своего первого бота для телеграмма.
Учусь по видео. Я решил использовать код автора (который у него вполне нормально работает), но у меня вылазит ошибка, с которой я никак не могу справиться. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Ошибка полностью:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Никита\Desktop\ТГбот.py", line 1, in 
from aiogram import Bot, types, executor, Dispatcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram_*init*_.py)**

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, executor, Dispatcher
import logging
import os 
from pytube import YouTube

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token = '')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executer.start_polling(dp)``
```

Comment: Код опубликовал полностью

Comment: I tried it. Does not work

Comment: необязательно на английском. здесь и на русском прекрасно поймут.

Comment: pip install --force-reinstall -v "aiogram==2.23.1" тогда только откатываться на старую версию. Или не использовать executer.

Comment: уже откатывался

Comment: Я прям очень много перепробовал

Comment: `pip list` проверьте  точно у вас aiogram 2.23.1 ?

Comment: Хотя стоп. пишет что 3.3.0, и когда пытаюсь установить мне выдает ошибку

Comment: В cmd пишет что отказано в доступе! Ребят подскажите с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Войдите в `cmd` с правами администратора.

Comment: все равно пишет что отказано в доступе

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у блогера стоит 2 версия aiogram, а у вас 3. В новой версии чтоб запустить бота нужно сделать так:

```
dp.start_polling(bot)
```

Примеры ботов на новой версии aiogram: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/tree/dev-3.x/examples

Так же у вас ошибка на последней строке: executer -> executor

Если хотите использовать старую версию обновите ее с помощью команды:

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall "aiogram<3"
```

Comment: Попытался обновить, вылезла вот такая ошибка ```ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:\\Users\\Никита\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\~.ltidict\\_multidict.cp311-win_amd64.pyd'```

cmd запускал от имени администратора 
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Так же попробовал запустить код как вы сказали, все равно выдает ошибку - ```ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'```